# wordpress site administrator user does not show woocommerce settings access after adding user role editor plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

[image: wp admin screenshot]

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ This plugin I installed
how to revert back I disable the plugin but still, I can't access woo-commerce admin access

it only shows me the order and coupon menu.

how to fixed this, please help

Answer (score 1):

i think you have not given shop manager rights to admin user so this is happening

/* solution */
you again activate above plugin and Grant role from that selected admin user
you can check screenshot given in user-role-editor plugin also

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue from the office plugin documents https://www.role-editor.com/how-to-restore-deleted-wordpress-user-roles/

```
3rd variant – User Role Editor creates roles backup record before save the very 1st update to them. You need to use SQL tool like phpMyAdmin. Find that record at ‘wp_options’ meta database table:
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='wp_backup_user_roles';
As the result you will see something like this (I use MySQL Workbench):
User Roles Auto Backup
User Roles Auto Backup

Take data from the option_value field and place them into the record where WordPress stores user roles originally. You may find it with this SQL query:
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='wp_user_roles';
Read this post for more details about changing WordPress user roles directly in the database using SQL commands.
```